# What is meant by ‘whole tracts’ in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is meant by ‘whole tracts’ in this passage. I know that ‘tract’ means ‘area’, ‘portion’, etc. and of course I know what ‘whole’ means, but I don’t understand the meaning of them in the context. It was said before that the Earth is largely affected by humans, yet here in this sentence it says it is largely unaffected. Am I missing something here?

> There have been many different conceptions of nature across the cen-
> turies. For some, nature is everything that is not supernatural, and
> in this sense humanity is generally regarded as part of nature. For
> others, the natural is everything that is not (or largely not) the
> result of human artifice or intervention, and in this sense humanity
> is often regarded as distinct from nature, since most people are
> formed by human nurturing and education. The parenthetic ‘or largely
> not’ is important, for the regions of Earth unaffected by humanity are
> diminishingly slight, and in some views nonexistent. Yet **whole tracts**
> are largely unaffected, and it is these tracts and their living
> inhabitants that are most often meant when people speak of ‘nature’.

Comment: have you checked a dictionary? google it and you will find out right away.

Comment: Very little of the Earth is completely unaffected by human activities, but _whole tracts_ (large areas) are _largely unaffected_ (very little affected).

Comment: @fev Google what? Check what? My question is not about the dictionary meaning of the words, it is about the meaning in the context. Please read the question again.

Comment: @KateBunting So there are very little that are unaffected but there are large areas that are largely unaffected. Seems contradictory!

Comment: That's why the author says that the parenthetic 'or largely not' is important! A wilderness area may have a few roads and dwellings but still include large tracts of land without industry or agriculture.

Answer (score 1):

I am obliged to start with definitions that you already know. For example:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whole)
> whole:
> complete or not divided:
> *I spent the whole day cleaning*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whole)
> Whole:
> constituting the total sum or undiminished entirety
> 3a: entire:
> *owns the whole island*
> 3b: each or all of the
> *took part in the whole series of athletic events*
> 4a: constituting an undivided unit: Unbroken

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tract)
> Tract:
> a large area of land

The phrase *whole tracts* thus refers to areas of land that are whole, of one piece, of a unity. We see this in some online examples.

Referring to pieces of land within a country, each piece being whole and undivided:

> [Asian Lii](http://www.asianlii.org/cn/legis/cen/laws/iroefiitdamowtol1007/)
> *Interim Regulations on Encouraging Foreign Investment in the Development and Management of Whole Tracts of Land*

Referring to areas of land suitable for tulips, each area complete in itself:

> [Fauna and Flora International](https://www.fauna-flora.org/news/which-plants-and-animals-are-affected-by-climate-change-some-of-the-names-may-surprise-you/)
> *you might be surprised to learn that a warming world is bad news for wild tulips, all of which are destined to lose whole tracts of suitable native habitat.*

A wider use of *tract*, loosely referring to areas of land but actually referring to those areas (=whole parts, or whole distinguishable groups) of economic society in which there are skills shortages. These economic tracts may be associated with implied regional land tracts, such as coalfield areas, agricultural areas, working class urban areas, coastal areas and so forth:

> [Times Higher Education](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/blog/ditch-old-hierarchies-further-and-higher-education-belong-together)
> *In the context of Brexit, problems with the skills system cannot be ignored. As the recent report from the Social Mobility Commission said, “whole tracts of our country feel left behind, because they are”*.

With all this in mind, your example refers to a class of areas of land, each whole in itself, that are only slightly affected (= your quoted "largely unaffected") by humanity, despite humanity's great effect on the whole earth.

For example, some areas of the Amazonian rainforest remain pristine despite the destructive human pressures on the whole Amazon basin. Or, there are still almost natural tracts in the Appalachians in north America, despite there also being ruined Appalachian coalfield areas.

In other words, "almost natural" tracts still exist on Earth, despite there being so many other tracts of land that have been ruined by humanity.